# Release Management cannot find build artifacts

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

We are trying to set up Release Management on prem and am running into an issue.  We have our TFS server and Build Server(running RM and Build Agent) on separate machines.  We also have 3 domain users: rmserver (Running RM Server), rmagent (To deploy build on target machine) and rmtfsint(to communicate between RM and TFS).

The project builds successfully and puts the artifacts in the shared drop folder.

When I go into RM and click New Release and then Latest Build, I get the following error:

[image: Release Management Error]

When I click OK, RM does pick up the latest build number (not sure if this comes from TFS or RM)

I am connecting to TFS using the rmtfsint domain user.  It seems like this user cannot access TFS to get the build location to release.
The rmtfsint user is in TFS as Project Collection Service Account. And 'Make requests on behalf of others' is set to allow. The domain users all have access to the drops share and are also administrators on the 2 servers.  They are also users in Release Management. 
All the servers involved are in the same IP range so I am told it is not a firewall issue.

I have used fiddler to try and get some more information and the error comes from calling the GetPackageLocation on the releasemangementservice, but that doesn't really tell me much.

Has anyone come accross this issue?  It's the last piece of the juigsaw before we can start continuous integration!

Comment: Are you using the new vNext, task-based builds in TFS 2015?

Comment: Have you tried storing your drops not on a share but directly in the TFS server? This is an option on your build template. It's not a direct solution but it removes the share from the equation to make sure that's the problem.

Comment: does your build definition produce multiple drops? well in that case your component name should contain the name of the artifact that the build produces - this was a limitation with RM on-prem and build vNext from what I know.

Comment: Hi Daniel, we are using the new vNext task-based builds on TFS 2015 RC2.

Comment: Hi divyanhm, we have two drops called Debug and Release.  We did exactly as you suggested and changed the name of the component and it worked a treat.  Thank you so much.  That is such a weird quirk!  Thanks again.

Comment: @Mozza It's not a quirk, it's a technical requirement. The task-based build system can publish multiple sets of artifacts, so you have to differentiate between them somehow.